Exception: 'ElasticSearch' - Verify type-alias and check extension is included
I'm new to elastic search. I'm working with .net 4.5. I added all the necessary tags to
NLogConfig.xml but still get exception:
Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Failed to create Target with unknown type-alias: 'ElasticSearch' - Verify type-alias and check extension is included.
NLogConfig.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>


<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
</extensions>

<targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
    <!-- Uncomment the following lines for file logging -->
    <target xsi:type="EventLog" 
        name="eventLog" 
        layout="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}"    
        source="${event-properties:item=customSource}"
        eventId="${event-properties:EventId:whenEmpty=0:item=costumEventId}" />

    <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" name="****DEV" index="elasticsearch" documentType=""
    flushTimeout="5000">
        <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
       uri="http://****:9200/"
       includeAllProperties ="true">
        </target>
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <!-- <logger name="*" levels="Info,Error,Debug,Warn,Trace,Fail" writeTo="console" /> -->
    <logger name="*" levels="Info,Error" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" levels="Info,Debug,Error" writeTo="file" />
    <!-- <logger name="*" levels="Error" writeTo="email" /> -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="eventLog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info,Debug,Error" writeTo="elasticsearch" />
</rules>

